# Titanium: Passing a variable not working

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Trying to pass a parameter to addevent, but it's not working.

Putting the table together:

```
for (var i=0; i<json.objects[0].tour.length; i++){
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(
            title = json.objects[0].tour[i].name,
            leftImage = json.objects[0].tour[i].icon,
            hasChild = true,
            rowIndex = json.objects[0].tour[i].id,
            height = 68,
            rowId = i
    );

    var tourdetdatattlwrvw = Ti.UI.createView({top:10, left: 10, width:'100%',height:28});

    var tourdetdatattllbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:json.objects[0].tour[i].name,
        height:23,
        width:'100%',
        font:{fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold'},
        color:'#000',
        textAlign:'left'
    });

    tourdetdatattlwrvw.add(tourdetdatattllbl)

    var tourdetdatadescwrvw = Ti.UI.createView({left:10, width:'100%', top:40, height:60});

    var tourdetdatadesclbl = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text:json.objects[0].tour[i].description,
        font:{fontSize:12,fontWeight:'normal'},
        color:'#000',
        width:'100%',
        height:60
    });

    tourdetdatadescwrvw.add(tourdetdatadesclbl)

    row.add(tourdetdatattlwrvw);
    row.add(tourdetdatadescwrvw);
    tableData.push(row); 
}

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:tableData
});
```

Then the event listener:

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    activeTour = e.source.rowId;
    alert(activeTour)
        alert(rowIndex)
})
```

And of course it's not working.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in the following part of your code

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow(
    title = json.objects[0].tour[i].name,
    leftImage = json.objects[0].tour[i].icon,
    hasChild = true,
    rowIndex = json.objects[0].tour[i].id,
    height = 68,
    rowId = i
);
```

Try changing it to

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    title : json.objects[0].tour[i].name,
    leftImage : json.objects[0].tour[i].icon,
    hasChild : true,
    rowIndex : json.objects[0].tour[i].id,
    height : 68,
    rowId : i
});
```

and you can take the value as

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    activeTour = e.rowData.rowId;
     alert(activeTour);
});
```

Hope it helped you. Let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 1):

when you set any custom variable in your row object then you can get it back by below code so try it and tell me if you find any problem.

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    activeTour = e.row.rowId;
     alert(e.row.rowId);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try this

```
table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    activeTour = e.index;
alert(e.index)
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Index will work for the previous level. Since i'm 1 screen deep already, i need to know the previous parent (from the first click) in order for it to work.

Comment: To be more exact, user selects tour, then location. It works fine on selecting tour, it just refuses to pass value on location.

Comment: No, wait, my bad, this is happening on the tours window, so i cannot load the location, since i dont know what tour i'm in...